# Filter by different keys in React is incorrect

Tags: reactjs, filter, checkbox

I have an array with objects like

```
const users = [
    { name: 'John', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
    { name: 'Jinny', age: 30, gender: 'F', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
    { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' },
  ],
```

And a group of checkbox, which filter by country UK, gender F and age 15 or show all. After clicking on each filtered items from users are shown.
I write checked inputs in array and then use forEach.
But users filter incorrect. They filter separately, only by one condition, not as a whole.

```
const value = ['F', 'UK', 15];
const value = ['all'];

const showUsersFilter = () => {
    let users = users;
    value.forEach((item) => {
      switch (item) {
        case 'all':
          users = users;
          return users;
        case 'F':
          users = users.filter((user) => user.gender === 'F');
          return users;
        case 'UK':
          users = users.filter((user) => user.country === 'UK');
          return listUsers;
        case 15:
          users  = users.filter((user) => user.age === 15);
          return users ;
       default:
          return users;
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: explain more . show what is happening and what you want to happen

Comment: It should filter by checking checkboxes like here https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9yBS.png

Comment: @Festina Why dont you try users = users.filter((user)=> user.gender === 'F' && user.country === 'UK' && user.age === 15) in case 'all'

Answer (score 0):

When you ***return***, you exit the loop and the function; no further iterations are processed. You're returning users from within each case so the first match is all you get.

```js
case 'F':
  users = users.filter((user) => user.gender === 'F');
  return users; // exits the loop, exits the function; no further filtering
```

You might consider a more general approach that doesn't require you to add new logic every time you want to add or change the filters.

Consider the snippet below. To add another filter you'd just add another checkbox.

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'John', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
  { name: 'Jack', age: 20, gender: 'M', city: 'New York', country: 'USA' },
  { name: 'Jinny', age: 30, gender: 'F', city: 'London', country: 'UK' },
  { name: 'Key', age: 15, gender: 'M', city: 'Leeds', country: 'UK' },
];

const filters = {};

function filterUsers() {
  const filtered = users.filter(u => Object.entries(filters).every(([name, value]) => u[name] == value));
  console.clear();
  console.log(filtered);
}

function updateFilters(event) {
  const { name, value, checked } = event.target;
  if (checked) {
    filters[name] = value;
  }
  else {
    delete filters[name];
  }
  
  filterUsers();
}

document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]').forEach(box => box.addEventListener('change', updateFilters));
```

```html
<label><input type='checkbox' name="age" value="15" /> Age 15</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' name="city" value="Leeds" /> City Leeds</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' name="gender" value="M" /> Gender M</label>
```